# Implementing IMAP server

Tags: php, python, imap

I need to write an IMAP wrapper around some messaging system.
With all the complexity of IMAP protocol i'd rather use some existing library to do the heavy lifting for me.

Are there any IMAP servers / libraries / frameworks available in PHP or Python?

Alternatively, is there such IMAP server which would allow to write a driver to use custom messaging system as a backend?

Comment: Do you mean you need to write an IMAP server at the socket level? If so, PHP is *not* the best language to do this - look at Java or Node.js (or any other language of your choice that supports or mimics support for multithreading)...

Comment: Well, python then, though node.js could be an option. But it does not matter, the main question is whether there's something i can use to avoid writing actual IMAP layer.

Comment: Sorry, complete missed the Py references, was browsing the PHP tag and brain was in PHP mode... [Googling 'python IMAP server'](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python+imap+server) produces [this](http://packages.python.org/ProcImap/ProcImap.ImapServer-module.html) promising looking (second!!) result. Google is your friend...

Comment: That one is just a wrapper/proxy which uses imap client to connect to some server with given username and password. Unfortunately.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way you can implement this using POP3 or SMTP? They are much nicer/easier to implement...

Comment: @SvenMarnach that sounds like a good option. i suggest you put it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using Java then, [Apache James IMAP](http://james.apache.org/imap/index.html) provides RFC2040 compliant data access layer for IMAP. It is not fully optimized for performance yet but appears to be tested and in working condition otherwise. They also provide a full IMAP server and because everything is under Apache license, you should be able to use it as is or modify it any way you feel like.

Answer (score 0):

The Python library for writing protocol servers and clients with probably the best reputation is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It contains an implementation of an IMAP server (`twisted.mail.imap4.IMAP4Server`). From a quick glance, it seems you'd need to wrap your "mail boxes" in [this interface](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/mail/imap4.py#L5053).

(Note though that I never used this class and I'm not sure if this really works as I expect it to work.)